# Javascript Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am stuck with a regexp to test that a string contains only:

1. letters lowercase or uppercase
2. "." (dot sign)
3. digits
4. "_" (underscore sign)

any other character except above will need to be an invalid input

1dx.tex - OK

Ted_upcD.t3 - OK

$tex._ce - FAIL(invalid char$)

Thank you !

Comment: could post the code? So that we can see what is wrong.

Comment: what do you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[\w.]+$
```

This should do it....